# How to expose non-realtime metrics to Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I'm instrumenting an exporter, using Java client, that will expose metrics that potentially have been sitting in the buffer for a while to Prometheus. Each metric comes with a timestamp, so I know exactly when the metric was collected. However, I'm having a hard time using timestamp when constructing metrics, even though Collector.MetricFamilySamples.Sample class has a timestampMs field. This is especially hard for quantile metrics like Summary or Histogram. I can pass the metric value to it using Summary.observe(), but I can't also pass in a timestamp indicating the time of observation.

What's the right way to do this, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus isn't designed for this. The best thing to do would be to report the metric before it enters the buffer. Failing that, I'd suggest reporting the metrics as-is without timestamps, and living with the varying lag.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I ended up modifying the client_java library to support the "batch-mode" scrape of Summary-type metrics. In this mode, you can supply a timestamp to the Summary.observe() method. I hope this won't cause any issues on the server side.

Comment: @yty, does this way work for you? I am also finding how to export "batch-mode" data with timestamp.

Comment: @Muz Sorry, just saw your message. Yes it works. However, if your timestamp is too old (say a few days old), you will run into other issues.